# In what spaces does the notion of a gradient field make sense?

Tags: calculus, vector-bundles

I am doing highschool calculus, and I have been told a gradient field is a field $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=f_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n)e_1+\cdots f_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)e_n$ where we have $$F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\nabla q(x_1,\cdots,x_n).$$

(where $\{e_i\}$ are the standard basis vectors for $\Bbb R^n$)

So I guess this definition definitely has $\Bbb R^n$ in mind? Does this notion hold in other spaces? I get that we can define a vectorbundle on really any topological space, and since this notion is apparently equivalent to the notion of a being a conservative field, which seems like it should be very topological, it seems it should (hold in other spaces)?

Related is my previous question: [Understanding the conservative property of a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111099/understanding-the-conservative-property-of-a-vector-field)

> My previous question being related mainly in the sense that it seems that the force field is a section of a bundle, so then we should be able to give a value to each homotopy class of paths, with specific fixed end points, where I feel this is the real definition of a conservative field.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into too much detail on the definitions involved, on a *differential manifold* the generalization of the gradient is more naturally interpreted as a section of the *cotangent bundle*, also known as the space of *1-forms*.  In this form, the notation would look like:
\begin{equation*}
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} d x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} d x_n.
\end{equation*}

In general, though, there is a distinction between the 1-forms which can be expressed in this way, and the generally larger space of 1-forms $\omega$ which satisfy $d \omega = 0$ - I'm not sure which you take as the definition of a "conservative force field".  As an example, the restriction to the unit circle of
\begin{equation*}
\omega := -y\,dx + x\,dy
\end{equation*}
satisfies $d\omega = 0$ but there is no global function $\theta$ on the circle such that $\omega = d \theta$.  (However, there are some functions on subsets of the circle which satisfy this, such as $\theta := \tan^{-1}(y/x)$.)  The study of the difference between the two notions is the start of *de Rham cohomology* which is closely related to homotopy theory.